# Create a time span field

Tags: 6, entities, datetime

The date module provides a handy widget for specifying a date.  Is there something similar on Drupal 6 for specifying a length of time such as 6 months or 3 days?  The time span will need to be converted to or stored as seconds for use by my module.

Answer (score 2):

The [Interval Field](http://drupal.org/project/interval) module looks like it would do the trick.

> Interval field gives you a simple field and widget to allow users to enter interval values eg
>
> - 2 months
> - 3 days
> - 4 years

Comment: Good answer for 7, but I should have mentioned I'm on Drupal 6.  I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 1):

For Drupal 6, try the [Duration](http://drupal.org/project/duration) module.

Another great module for Drupal 7, is the [Time Period](http://drupal.org/project/timeperiod) module.